# Where to create KTX Files, no Plugin for Photoshop?

Tags: opengl, textures

Are there any Plugins out there for Photoshop to edit/create KTX Files? In Photoshop there are dds Plugins but i couldn't find any tools rather than this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZs21xda9lY which is a custom made one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any official ones, only open source and custom made ones. http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/ is another one that I've found.